# Intel GMA 950 missing driver for an EEE PC 1008HA

Tags: 11.10, intel-graphics

System info shows graphics unknown so I guess the slow response problem in unity is due to that. Is there any way to get some drivers to my card?

I have a GMA 950 graphics card and my computer is a Eeepc 1008HA.

Same on Dell Mini 9.

Comment: Same problem here, I have an Asus n53sv laptop with an Intel HD 3000 graphics adapter, which used to work out of the box in 11.4, but has stopped working in 11.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a similar situation to what I had with my Intel® 965GM. My system info was also showing my graphics card as unknown in Ubuntu 11.10, and after a while (a few days later I installed Ubuntu 11.10) my Unity 3D was broken. I could be able to select "Ubuntu" but it acted like I was using Unity 2D.

I found out that it is related to OpenGL and I applied this command:

1.Remove NVidia drivers

(I know you didn't install any NVidia drivers, I also didn't install but in my case there were NVidia drivers installed somehow.)

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

2.Remove your xorg.conf

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

3.Reinstall xorg completely

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64
```

4.Re-configure Xorg

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

5.Restart your computer

```
sudo reboot
```

After I applied all of these commands, my Unity 3D was back and when I check system info, this time Ubuntu recognized my Intel graphics.

Answer (score 0):

This is from Hardware Support Wiki 
I would suggest if you have a low-powered system you may want to try Lubuntu or resort to using something the hardware can support.

Asus Eee PC 1008HA

Works very well. Very nice optimization for this device!

Ubuntu Netbook Remix 9.10 Karmic i386

```
Wireless - working
Wired network card - working
Webcam - working
Microphone - working
Bluetooth - working (external)
Touchpad - working
Graphics card driver (1024x600) - working
Audio - working
Multi-touch not working (only with external script on boot)
Power managment - working
SD Card reader - working
Hardware buttons (sound volume, brightness, ...) - working
```

Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick i386

```
Wireless - working
Wired network card - working
Webcam - working
Microphone - working
Bluetooth - working
Touchpad - working (can`t disable it with "on/off" switch-button)
Graphics card driver (1024x600) - working
Audio - working
Multi-touch not working (only with external script on boot)
Power managment - working
SD Card reader - working
Hardware buttons (sound volume, brightness, wireless, sleep, ...) - working
```